# Finding sum of function

Tags: functions

The function $~f(x)~$ has the following properties

$i.\quad f(\frac{x}{x+1}) = \frac{1}{2} f(x)$

$ii.\quad f(1-x) = 1-f(x)$

for all positive real number $~x~$.

Find the value of $$S_n = f(1) + f\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) + f\left(\frac{1}{3}\right) + \cdots + f\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$$

Comment: Have you made any attempts at the problem?  For instance, can you determine the value of $f(1/2)$?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Note that, by replacing $n$ by $\frac{1}{n}$ in the first condition, you get, $$f\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)=2f\left(\frac{1}{n+1}\right)$$Therefore, $$S_n=f(1)+f\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)+f\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)+\cdots+f\left(\frac{1}{n}\right) =3f\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)+f\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)+\cdots+f\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\\ ~~~~~=5f\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)+f\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)+\cdots+f\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)=\cdots=(2^n-1)f\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$$
So, for you its enough to find $f(1/n)$. This is simple by first substituting $n=0$ in the first condition to get, $f(0)=\frac{f(0)}{2}\implies f(0)=0$. Now put $n=0$ in the second condition to get $f(1)=1-f(0)=1$. So we have $f(1)=1$ and $f\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)=2f\left(\frac{1}{n+1}\right)$. Now, call $f\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)=a_n$. Therefore, we have $a_n=2a_{n+1}$ which is a G.P. with $a_1=1$. So, $a_n=2^{n-1}$ by the formula of $n^{\mbox{th}}$ G.P. Hence, $f(1/n)=2^n\implies S_n=\frac{2^n-1}{2^{n-1}}$

Comment: Thank for your answer, it really give me idea to develop further for the solution.

Comment: Take 2 key idea from your solution, f(1) =1, and when it form the G.P. with r=2, the series become Sn = 1 + 1/2 + 1/4 + ..... +1/n. Take the sum of G.P., i think the answer should be Sn = 2 ( 1 - (1/2)^n).

Comment: Both answer are same.